# C++ Nested For Loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, visual-c++, nested-loops

I thought this would be easier than originally planned. I'm trying to make this image out of nested for loops:

[image]

Any suggestions or solutions would be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i<1;i++)
    {
        cout<<i+1<<endl;

        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            cout<<j+1;
        }
     }

    cout<<"\n";
    for(int k=0; k<3; k++)
    {
        cout<<k+1;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int l=0; l<4; l++)
    {
        cout<<l+1;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int m=4; m>0; m--)
    {
        cout<<m;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int n=3; n>0; n--)
    {
        cout<<n;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int o=2; o>0; o--)
    {
        cout<<o;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int p=0; p<1; p++)
    {
        cout<<p+1;
    }
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An image of the output of what you have created would be very useful in solving the problem.

Comment: Also do not use `i`, `j`, `k`, `l`, `m`, `n`, `o` as variable names. its very hard to understand the code

Comment: Hint: You'll want the bound of the inner loop to be the loop index of the outer loop

Comment: Consider breaking this into two problems: the top four rows then the bottom four rows. Try to solve for the top four rows before worrying about the rest of it.

Comment: I'm not that skilled with visual looping like this... Any code examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 /*first half: From level1 = 1 to less than 5, level2 = 1 to less than or equal to level1, print level2 */
 for(int level1 = 1; level1 < 5; level1++) { 
     for(int level2 = 1; level2 <= level1; level2++){
        cout << level2;
     }
     cout << '\n'; /*prints the newline AFTER each iteration of the `level2` loop*/
 }

 /*second half: reverse the logic of part1, but also add spaces in the beginning */
 for(int level1 = 4; level1 > 0; level1--){
     for(int interim = 4; interim > level1; interim--) cout << ' ';
     for(int level2 = level1; level2 > 0; level2--){
         cout << level2;
     }
     cout << '\n';
 }
 return 0;  
}
```

Let me know if you do not understand this code :-)

Comment: I do not fully, but the results are perfect.  Why name the variable interim and could you explain the logic please?

Comment: well I didnot know what to call the variable there, so called it something stupid like `interim` but You understand from the code that it is used only to add a space in the output.

Comment: Realized that the loop logic did two row levels going down through 4 etc.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution in C for you =)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char forward[5] = "1";
    char reverse[5] = "4321";

    int i;
    for( i = 1; i <= 4; i++ ) {
        printf( "%s\n", forward );
        forward[i] = forward[i-1]+1;
    }
    for( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) printf( "% 4s\n", reverse+i );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want an extremely compact and not very follow-able solution I decided to give it a shot.

```
int length = 4;

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{
    for(int j = 0; j < length; j++) 
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < (i == 1 ? length - j : j + 1); k++) 
        {
            if(i == 1 && k == 0) 
                for(int x = 0; x < j; x++)
                    cout << " ";

            cout << (i == 1 ? (length - k) - j : k + 1);
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Where `length` is the number of iterations from `1` to `length`.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, since paddy posted his C solution (and someone said "compact" =P)...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char line[] = "1234321";
    int i=0;
    for (; i<4; printf("%.*s\n",++i,line));
    for (i=0;i<4; printf("%4s\n",line+3+i++));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1
12
123
1234
4321
 321
  21
   1
```